# "class diagram"-like thing for Backbone.js models and views?

Tags: backbone.js, uml, diagram, rubymine

I'd love to be able to see something like RubyMine's model diagrams but for the Backbone.js parts of my project. Anyone know of a tool that does something like that?

Answer (score 1):

There is a UML plugin for Eclipse called [jsuml](http://jsuml.gaertner-network.de/).  I have no experience with it myself, and by looking at the description on its web page, it seems that your code should be annotated in some way.  (e.g. JSDoc)